# Flutter app not running on iOS but running on Android

Tags: flutter

I don't know how to structure or ask this question but here it is.

I'm on MacOS Sanoma and my test device is a physical iPhone 13 running iOS 17 beta.

When I create a flutter app and run this app using Xcode, I get the following error. I have wasted hours trying to figure it out. What am I missing here?

[image]

I can confirm that this is only a problem when I use my iPhone 13 mini. I have tried to clear my Developer settings.

[image]

Comment: Check out my answer if still not working in IOS 17.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the solution to my problem question above, just some information.
FYI - the issue seems to be related to my target device - an iPhone 13 running iOS 17 beta. Once I downgraded to iOS 16, everything started working as normal.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are running at least at V3.13.7.

It was an issue in Flutter SDK with IOS 17.
It is now resolved. [Merged Request](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/128531)

***So, Just update your flutter to run the app on iPhone with IOS 17.***

Comment: Please don't post the exact same answer under multiple questions

Comment: What if answer is same for both question?

Comment: If both questions adress the same problem, mark them as duplicates

Answer (score 0):

### In you Mac

`Goto system settings -> Privacy & settings -> Files and Folders ->and then  add Xcode`

Which will be solve you'r problem

Comment: Already there. Still doesn't work. However, weirdly, it does work if I run the same project on my iPhone 7 running iOS 15.

Comment: Are you using Xcode beta or not?

Comment: Yeah, I'm using Xcode beta.